# Como faço para ordenar string no metodo Insertion sort?

Tags: java, array, string

Estou com o seguinte método, porém na linha do WHILE ele da erro. O netbeans diz

> "bad operand types for binary operator "&&", first type: boolean, second type: int".

```
public boolean insertionSort(String a []) {
        if (a == null) return false;   
        int i,j;  String x;
        for ( i=0; i < a.length; i++ ) {       
            x = a[i]; j = i;
            while (j>0  && x.compareTo(a[j-1])) {
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            a[j] = x;
            visualizarEtapa(a,i);
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `.compareTo` retorna um int (-1 para menor, 0 para igual e 1 para maior).
Deste modo, para vc comparar você pode usar:

```
while (j>0  && 0 == x.compareTo(a[j-1]))
```

ou

```
while (j>0  && x.equals(a[j-1]))
```

ou ainda utilizando o 
[commons lang3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) da apache

```
while (j>0  && StringUtils.equals(x.compareTo(a[j-1]))
```

Existem diversas formas para se comparar strings, nos dois primeiros exemplos vc precisa tomar muito cuidado para evitar [NullPointException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) quando x for nulo, fazendo sempre validações antes de trabalhar com o `.compareTo` ou com o `.equals`

**Codigo editado**

```
public boolean insertionSort(String a []) {
        if (a == null) return false;   
        int i,j;  String x;
        for (j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {       
            x = a[j]; i = j - 1;

            while (i >= 0) {
                if (x.compareTo(a[i]) > 0) {
                    break;
                }
                a[i + 1] = a[i];
                i--;
            }
            a[i + 1] = x;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Porém o método ainda não estava ordenando os valores do vetor alfabeticamente.
Troquei o comparativo "==" para ">". Ficou assim:
while (j>0  && 0 > x.compareTo(a[j-1]))

Comment: peguei seu codigo fiz algumas alteracoes, veja se funciona